# Week Number Incorrect in Morris.js

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I check the week number via [here](http://whatweekisit.com/). I checked week 29 is from 12th July 2015 - 18th July 2015. But in morris chart, w29 is 19th - 25th July 2015. Where can I correct this quickly?

[image]

//js

```
var line = new Morris.Line({
        element: 'line-chart',
        resize: true,
        data: result_week,
        xkey: 'week',
        ykeys: ['price'],
        labels: ['Price'],
        xLabels: ['week'],
        lineColors: ['#3c8dbc'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        smooth: false
    });
```

Also, any way can show the x-axis label as '2015-W29' instead of date format?

Please advice. Thank you.

**UPDATE :
I changed morris.js by minus the week -1, I know it's not right by minus 1. But still hope for better solution. The question is still open! Thanks.**

```
"week": {
  span: 604800000,
  start: function(d) {
    return new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
  },
  fmt: function(d) {
    // return "" + (d.getFullYear()) + "-" + (Morris.pad2(d.getMonth() + 1)) + "-" + (Morris.pad2(d.getDate()));
    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
    }

    return "" + (d.getFullYear()) + " W" + (Morris.pad2(d.getWeek() - 1));
  },
  incr: function(d) {
    return d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
  }
},
```

Comment: It depends on how you define the 1st week of the year.

Comment: @zerkms I never define. Where to define? please advice.

Comment: I didn't mean a programmatic definition, but a term definition. In some cases the first week starts with the first monday of the year, sometimes - with the Jan 1st. And both are "valid".

Answer (score 1):

One way is to [provide your own `hoverCallback()` function](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html):

> Provide a function on this option to generate custom hover legends. 
>   The function will be called with the index of the row under the hover legend, the options object passed to the constructor as arguments, a string containing the default generated hover legend content HTML, and an object containing the original data for the row as passed in the data option.

In that function, you can adjust the week number displayed (either override the `content` completely or amend only the week number).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same issue. You could solve defining your own *dateFormat* and *xLabelFormat* functions.

Those functions provide you unix epoch time as only parameter. Using weeks for X axis the unix epoch time will be wrong: you must subtract 7 days (as you already understand).

Definitely not a solution but it doesn't require any change in main library.
Hoping someone will fix this issue as soon as possible.